# Season is not abstract and does not override abstract method printMonths() in Season

Tags: java

"Write an enum named Season with 4 constants: WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL. It contains a final field named averageTemperature, initialized by a constructor and with a getter method. Additionally, it also contains an abstract method named printMonths() which will display the months in that respective season. Traverse all values of this enum and display the season, average temperature, and the months of that season."

```
public enum Season {
    WINTER(-5.0, new String[]{"December", "January", "February"}),
    SPRING(15.0, new String[]{"March", "April", "May"}),
    SUMMER(25.0, new String[]{"June", "July", "August"}),
    FALL(10.0, new String[]{"September", "October", "November"});
    @Override
    public abstract void printMonths(){
        this.months = months;
        this.averageTemperature = averageTemperature;
    };
    private final double averageTemperature;
    private final String[] months;

    Season(double averageTemperature, String[] months) {
        this.averageTemperature = averageTemperature;
        this.months = months;
    }

    public double getAverageTemperature() {

        return averageTemperature;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println("Season: " + this.name());
        System.out.println("Average temperature: " + this.getAverageTemperature() + " degrees Celsius");
        System.out.print("Months: ");
        this.printMonths();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain the problem ? Rather than posting your homework, your code and expect someone to fix it

Comment: An abstract method is a method without a method body. Yet, your abstract method has a body. This is invalid syntax, as the compiler surely has told you.

Comment: I removed the body from the abstract method and its still the same error, also i tried to override the method and it gives me another error :"Method does not override method from its superclass"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the method is abstract, it shouldn't have a body **and** should be implemented in each instance : each season

```java
enum Season {
    WINTER(-5.0) {
        @Override
        public void printMonths() {
            System.out.println("December, January and February");
        }
    },
    SPRING(15.0) {
        @Override
        public void printMonths() {
            System.out.println("March, April and May");
        }
    },
    SUMMER(25.0) {
        @Override
        public void printMonths() {
            System.out.println("June, July and August");
        }
    },
    FALL(10.0) {
        @Override
        public void printMonths() {
            System.out.println("Septembre, October and November");
        }
    };

    private final double averageTemperature;

    Season(double averageTemperature) {
        this.averageTemperature = averageTemperature;
    }

    public abstract void printMonths();

    public double getAverageTemperature() {
        return averageTemperature;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println("Season: " + this.name());
        System.out.println("Average temperature: " + this.getAverageTemperature() + " degrees Celsius");
        System.out.print("Months: ");
        this.printMonths();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Then use like

```
for (Season s : Season.values()) {
    s.printInfo();
}
```

```
Season: WINTER
Average temperature: -5.0 degrees Celsius
Months: December, January and February

Season: SPRING
Average temperature: 15.0 degrees Celsius
Months: March, April and May

Season: SUMMER
Average temperature: 25.0 degrees Celsius
Months: June, July and August

Season: FALL
Average temperature: 10.0 degrees Celsius
Months: Septembre, October and November
```